# Haskell takeWhile + 1

Tags: haskell

How can I write a takeWhile that would keep the first element that doesn't match the condition?

Example (obviously my example is trickier than this) :

Instead of `takeWhile (\× - > x! = 3) [1..10]` to return `[1,2]` I need `[1,2,3]`.

I thought of `(takeWhile  myFunc myList) ++ [find myFunc myList]` but it means I need to go through my list 2 times...

Any idea?

Comment: Have you considered to write it as a `fold`? Using the pattern `foldr step base` you can write any function like this on lists.

Comment: In case it's not clear from chi's answer `takeWhile` and other `base` functions are not magic: they're implemented in haskell and you can view the source, copy-paste and modify them, etc. Most are one-liners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can roll your own.

```
takeWhileOneMore :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhileOneMore p = foldr (\x ys -> if p x then x:ys else [x]) []
```

Compare it with

```
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile p = foldr (\x ys -> if p x then x:ys else []) []
```

Explicit recursion would also be fine for this.

```
takeWhileOneMore :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhileOneMore p [] = []
takeWhileOneMore p (x:xs) = 
   if p x
   then x : takeWhileOneMore p xs
   else [x]
```

Comment: Thanks! I realize I'm not comfortable yet enough with `foldr`. I thought of `takeWhileOneMore p list = take (fromJust . findIndex (not. p) list) list` since. It is also correct, right? How do you compare the 2 solutions?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger `fromJust` is best to be avoided. It will crash your program when fed with `Nothing`. All the potentially-crashing functions like `head, tail, fromJust, ...` are rarely needed, and usually it's better to work pretending they don't exist, exploiting pattern matching and/or safer ("total") functions. I added a more basic alternative above, without `foldr`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `span` or `break`.

```
λ> span (/=3) [1..10]
([1,2],[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

So you can do something like this:

```
takeWhileInc :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhileInc p xs = case zs of [] -> error "not found"
                               (z:_) -> ys ++ [z]
  where
    (ys, zs) = span p xs
```

(Or whatever you want to happen when `zs` is empty because no `3`
was found.)

Comment: `foo p xs = let { (ys, zs) = span p xs } in ys ++ take 1 zs = uncurry (++) . second (take 1) . span p $ xs` . works either way whether `zs` is empty or not, no need to test.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the base function more than many people do, such as re-using `takeWhile` in an intelligent way to get the desired result.  For example, you can create a new list of predicates with the first element being `True` and `takeWhile` this list is true:

```
takeWhileP1 p xs = map snd (takeWhile fst (zip (True:map p xs) xs)
```

This generalizes nicely as well (not necessarily efficient in this form):

```
takeWhilePlusN n p xs = map snd (takeWhile fst (zip (replicate n True ++ map p xs) xs))
```

Or perhaps easier to read:

```
takeWhilePlusN n p xs =
  let preds     = replicate n True ++ map p xs
      annotated = zip preds xs
  in map snd (takeWhile fst annotated)
```

And the result:

```
*Main> takeWhilePlusN 3 (<5) [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
*Main> takeWhilePlusN 1 (<5) [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,5]
*Main> takeWhileP1 (<5) [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,5]
*Main> takeWhile (<5) [1..10]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

When the condition fails for a element, instead of terminating with empty list, we can return the element.

```
takeWhileInclusive :: (a->Bool)  -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhileInclusive _ [] = []
takeWhileInclusive predicate (x:xs) = if predicate x 
                                         then do (x: takeWhileInclusive predicate xs)
                                            else [x]
```

Comment: [`do (a:b)` is the same as `(a:b)`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info), and then your code is just `takeWhileOneMore` from chi's answer.